# how to show asp.net form using javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

i am making one login page in asp.net for that i have used one template from

http://codepen.io/andytran/pen/PwoQgO

as i know asp.net page can have only one form tag with runat="server" 
i want to write some code behind functionality on these 2 form tag.

```
 <form runat="server" visible="true" id="form1"> 
       .....
</form>

<form runat="server" visible="false" id="form2">
        ........
</form>
```

i have this div tag which is acting as toggle button

```
 <div class='switch' onclick="show();" >
<i class='fa fa-pencil fa-times' onclick="show()"></i>
```

and my javascript is :

```
   function show()
    {
        document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

but this code is not working..
Please help

Comment: What means "not working"? Did you get some error message?

Comment: what error do you get? also, in WebForms, as you said, you can only have one form on a page, hidden or not.

Comment: no i am not getting any error ... but my form2 is hidden..i am not getting form2

Comment: it should display="none" instead of visible="false"

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a form on the server will not render it to the client. You need to set CSS to hide it so you can show it.

```
<form style="display:none" />
```

and

```
..style.display="block";
```

and most likely your form is not going to be form1 and form2 unless you have it set up to render static ids.

Comment: when i am writing <form runat="server"  style="display:none" id="form2">  it is giving me an error that A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Comment: well than you need to change your code to only have one serverside form tag and make it so the form inside changes. Or don't use severside forms.

Comment: but i have code behind functionality on both the form

Comment: if you need two server side forms on the same page.. then load one form inside iframe. although you can use both registration and login form inside the same server side form. just put them in different div's and show hide these divs